# Adjusting the plot axis automatically in R

Tags: r, plot, charts, stock

I'm analyzing historical stock prices data which captures years of information. As part of the analysis I would like to be picking out shorter time periods and plotting straight lines through the pivot points, i.e. through the highs and lows, appearing on the stock charts.

Can someone please share an example of a script in R that automatically adjusts y and x axis to stretch and widen or condense them in a manner that would result in the slope of the straight line that is drawn through the pivot points equaling 1 or -1(i.e. y=x or y=-x)?

I have tried searching for the solution, but could not find anything that provides an automatic method for adjusting the axis. If possible, I would like the computer to determine how to adjust the axis to achieve the uniform change in the unit of price on Y axis as compared to the change in the unit of time on X axis. Thanks

[image]

```
# =============================================
# Clear environment
# =============================================
rm(list=ls())
# =============================================


# =============================================
# Load packages
# =============================================
if (!require("cwhmisc")) install.packages("cwhmisc")
library( cwhmisc )

if (!require("BatchGetSymbols")) install.packages("BatchGetSymbols")
library( BatchGetSymbols )
# =============================================


# =============================================
# inflect function
# =============================================
inflect <- function(x, threshold = 1){
  up   <- sapply(1:threshold, function(n) c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n)))
  down <-  sapply(-1:-threshold, function(n) c(rep(NA,abs(n)), x[-seq(length(x), length(x) - abs(n) + 1)]))
  a    <- cbind(x,up,down)
  list(minima = which(apply(a, 1, min) == a[,1]), maxima = which(apply(a, 1, max) == a[,1]))
}

# =============================================
# Set dates
# =============================================
W1.date <- as.Date("2020-01-03") # Whole Range Start Date
W2.date <- as.Date("2020-02-22") # Whole Range End   Date
# =============================================

# =============================================
frequency <- 'daily' # set frequency
ticker    <- "PBR"   # set ticker
# =============================================


# =============================================
# Pull out data from Yahoo
# =============================================
l.out <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = ticker, 
                         first.date   = W1.date,
                         last.date    = W2.date, 
                         freq.data    = frequency,
                         cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 'BGS_Cache') ) # cache in tempdir()
# =============================================
#l.out
#names(l.out)
#names(l.out$df.tickers)
# =============================================


# =============================================
# Create Whole Range dataframe
# =============================================
sDF <- as.data.frame(l.out$df.tickers)
#Check# sDF
# =============================================


# =============================================
# Pick a desired threshold # to plot up to
# =============================================
n <- 2
# Generate Data
# randomwalk <- 100 + cumsum(rnorm(50, 0.2, 1)) # climbs upwards most of the time
randomwalk <- sDF$price.close

bottoms <- lapply(1:n, function(x) inflect(randomwalk, threshold = x)$minima)
tops    <- lapply(1:n, function(x) inflect(randomwalk, threshold = x)$maxima)
# Color functions
cf.1 <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("pink","red"))
cf.2 <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("cyan","blue"))
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(randomwalk, type = 'l', main = "Minima & Maxima\nVariable Thresholds")
for(i in 1:n){
  points(bottoms[[i]], randomwalk[bottoms[[i]]], pch = 16, col = cf.1(n)[i], cex = i/1.5)
}
for(i in 1:n){
  points(tops[[i]], randomwalk[tops[[i]]], pch = 16, col = cf.2(n)[i], cex = i/1.5)
}
legend("topleft", legend = c("Minima",1:n,"Maxima",1:n), 
        pch = rep(c(NA, rep(16,n)), 2), col = c(1, cf.1(n),1, cf.2(n)), 
        pt.cex =  c(rep(c(1, c(1:n) / 1.5), 2)), cex = .75, ncol = 2)
# 
bottoms
tops
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could share some sample data, and perhaps also better illustrate what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: The intent is clear at this point, but sample data is missing, and it's hard to know where you're starting. Do you have the "pivot points" and models identified? Or are you starting with a big data set that you need help detecting those points and subsetting the data around it? If you give us good input in valid R syntax it becomes easy to help you. Without that, the first step in helping you becomes "guess what your data looks like".

Comment: Three good ways to share data: (1) use a built-in data set, (2) use `dput()` on a data object you have to share a copy/pasteable version of it, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows of `your_data`, (3) share code to simulate fake data (use `set.seed()` so any randomness is reproducible!).

Comment: I have added the code above. In there, the source for the data is included, it comes from Yahoo, for the the ticker "PBR" from Jan 2, 2020 to Feb 22, 2020. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe the function that you are looking for is the following:

```r
coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

This is a function part of the ggplot package that you can set a ratio for, in this case you would want 1. Additional arguments can be provided to set it to start at 0 etc.

The documentation can be found here:

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html

I have written a quick example of its usage in a reproducible example below.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Construct generic data
x = 1:100
y = rep(2, 100)

df <- tibble(x = x, y= y)

# Plot incorrect graph
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, linetype = 2, color = "red") +
  ylim(c(0, 200))
```

[image]

```r
# Plot graph with x, y axis 1:1
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, linetype = 2, color = "red") +
  ylim(c(0, 200))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the great solution, really appreciate the suggestion and definitely going to work with this function. I am using yahoo historical stock data, which is basically daily closing prices, and drawing straight lines through the pivot points on the stock charts results in these lines having their slope anywhere from 0 to 180 degrees. Is there a way to first determine what this initial slope or the angle of the line is before the x and y axis are adjusted? And then I am hoping based on that determination make the adjustment to the axis using coord_fixed.  Thanks again

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you shouldn't need to set the x and yaxis limits at all I have done so to illustrate the change in shape. Co-Ord fixed should always be 1 if you want y=x.

If you want the y=x line to be at different angles would it be possible to clarify how you know the angle that you want?

Comment: If I was to draw the line through the upper pivot points as shown on the chart above, often it does not have the slope of 45 or actually 135 degrees in this case. I would like make the script automatically adjust the X and Y axis so that the stock chart is stretched out or squeezed in, in such manner that would result in the slope of this specific straight line drawn through the pivot points being in fact with the slope of -1 or 135 degrees, regardless of what that initial slope was to begin with. In order to do so I need to be able to have the script determine that initial scope or angle

Comment: I see how coord_fixed is useful, I am just hoping to be able to have the script analyze the initial angle/slope of this straight line and then have it adjust the x and y axis to achieve the 45 degree slope. Once again the thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have the equation y = mx + c for your line then you-ll set the ratio as m for co-ord fixed I believe (you may want to be careful when m = 0 however).

Comment: That's the issue - I don't have the equation for this initial line before the adjustments are made to axis. I would like the script to determine this "m" factor and then adjust the graph/chart accordingly to stretch out or squeeze in the axis to achieve the factor of 1 or -1

Comment: I don't actually know how you are calculating the line from the data at the moment or how you would like to? It would be helpful if you could provide a specific example of what you  need to do to calculate this line.

Comment: Right, I am still looking for the ways to draw the straight line connecting those high pivot points. But I figured it should not be a difficult task, although if you have suggestions, please provide. And what I am struggling with at  the moment is the ability to determine the slope of the line and then adjust the chart to make that line -45 or 45 degrees.

Comment: If you could give suggestions on the script above, it would be great.

Comment: Running the script doesn't appear to plot the line so I am still confused as to what line is actually being drawn. Just the line graph and the colour marked points.

Is the line a regression between the points? It doesn't seem to be connected to any of the points marked on the graph in your image of the plot?

I may just be confused as to what the pivot points are sorry?

Comment: That’s correct , I’m still working on this script, I still need to add a way to draw a straight line to the script. The pivot points are the points of turn around, the peaks , noted in colour on the graph. Thanks

Comment: Again I am confused which points as the line you have drawn on doesn't lie on any of the points in colour? Is it a regression through all minima and maxima?

Comment: I still need to add the line you are absolutely right. And yes it is the straight regression line through the maximum and minimum points. Sorry for not being clear about it.

Comment: Joel, if you have suggestions for as to how to draw a straight line connecting two pivot points , it would be great. Thanks again